# reshape wide to long with indicator vector

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v11=rnorm(1), v12=rnorm(1), v21=rnorm(1), v31=rnorm(1), v41=rnorm(1), v42=rnorm(1), v43=rnorm(1))
```

this data frame has only one row

```
df
#          v11       v12        v21       v31       v41       v42       v43
# 1 -0.4425873 0.6062714 -0.3816921 0.2477926 0.1292103 0.2801346 0.4290997
```

Some columns are repeated observations for the same subject, for example `v11` and `v12` are two observations from the same subject.
`v21` and `v32` are only single observations. `v4x` has three observations.

I want to reshape the data frame to look like this:

```
v11  v21 v31  v41
v12   NA  NA  v42
 NA   NA  NA  v43
```

Note that it should contain the values of the variables not their names.

I have a indicator vector that marks which observation is what:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

Each "1" marks the start of a new column.

My first idea was to build each row on its own:

```
row1 <- df[, v == 1]
row2 <- df[, v == 2]
row3 <- df[, v == 3]
```

but this does not contain the NAs. 
There must be an easier way.

**Note:** A solution should not have to depend on the original column names `v11`, `v41`, etc, but only on the vector `v`.

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

v <- c(1,2,1,1,1,2,3)

df %>%
  gather(var, value) %>%
  mutate(row_num = v,
         col_num = paste0("v", cumsum(v==1))) %>%
  select(-var) %>%
  spread(col_num, value)
```

**Result:**

```
  row_num         v1       v2         v3        v4
1       1 -0.5604756 1.558708 0.07050839 0.1292877
2       2 -0.2301775       NA         NA 1.7150650
3       3         NA       NA         NA 0.4609162
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(v11 = -0.560475646552213, v12 = -0.23017748948328, 
    v21 = 1.55870831414912, v32 = 0.070508391424576, v41 = 0.129287735160946, 
    v42 = 1.71506498688328, v43 = 0.460916205989202), .Names = c("v11", 
"v12", "v21", "v32", "v41", "v42", "v43"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks, but it this generalizable? In my real data set the variable names are totally different and have no endings that indicate which observations they are. It's just in the vector `v`

Comment: @spore234 Without the variable names, how else would you know which column/row an element should be? I thought the premise of your question is that you do have those consistent variable names. For example let's say your variable names are now from `a` to `g`, how are you supposed to know that `a` and `b` are in column 1?

Comment: you are right, I made a mistake in my example. The first row is always complete. So each new "1" indicates the start of a new column.

Comment: @spore234 I see, so the column/rows should be based solely on the indicator vector `v`?

Comment: yes, correct. It should be like: "if 1 appears start new column, if not a 1 fill row x".

Comment: @spore234 Not clear at all. For example your last entry `v43` has no "1" anywhere; how do you know where to place it, if it doesn't adhere to the `vij` notation?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I think OP is talking about `1` in the indicator vector `v`. So something like `cumsum(v==1)` takes care of the column index

Comment: @userR Ah yes, I see now. Nice solution +1. I was still wrapping my head around what OP wanted...

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with `melt` and `dcast` from `reshape2` and `transform`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(transform(melt(df),
                rownum = substr(variable,3,3),
                cols = substr(variable,1,2)),
      rownum ~ cols, value.var = 'value')
```

The result:

```
  rownum          v1        v2        v3          v4
1      1  1.43420148 0.7391372 -1.758605 -0.06982523
2      2 -0.07729196        NA        NA  0.45190553
3      3          NA        NA        NA -1.95836646
```

Data:

```
set.seed(2017)
df <- data.frame(v11=rnorm(1), v12=rnorm(1), v21=rnorm(1), v31=rnorm(1), v41=rnorm(1), v42=rnorm(1), v43=rnorm(1))
```

Comment: This is similar to my original answer, but OP mentioned that the reshaping should not be based on the original column names but solely on the indicator vector `v` provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in base `R`, and only depends on your vector `v` that groups the measurement data:

First, example data:

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(v11=rnorm(1), v12=rnorm(1), v21=rnorm(1), v31=rnorm(1), v41=rnorm(1), v42=rnorm(1), v43=rnorm(1))

#       v11        v12      v21      v31       v41      v42       v43
#1 1.262954 -0.3262334 1.329799 1.272429 0.4146414 -1.53995 -0.928567


v <- c(1,2,1,1,1,2,3)
```

Then do:

```
v_grp <- cumsum(v == 1) # create index that groups the measurement data

out <- split(unlist(df), v_grp) # split vector of measurements by group

## following required to pad split vectors with `NA`.
## There are packages that give functions that do this

max_in_group <- max(summary(factor(v_grp)))    
out <- lapply(out, function(v) {
    num_in_vec <- length(v)
    if (num_in_vec < max_in_group) {
        v <- c(v, rep(NA, max_in_group - num_in_vec))
    }
    return(unname(v))
})


out <- do.call(cbind, out)

out
#              1        2        3          4
# v11  1.2629543 1.329799 1.272429  0.4146414
# v12 -0.3262334       NA       NA -1.5399500
#             NA       NA       NA -0.9285670
```

Comment: This works, and is faster than the "tidyr" approach, but seems like overkill!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for using matrix indexing, as you already have your row indices.

Here's how it can be done:

```
M <- matrix(NA, nrow = max(v), ncol = sum(v == 1))
M[cbind(v, cumsum(v == 1))] <- unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)
M
#            [,1]     [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] -0.5604756 1.558708 0.07050839 0.1292877
# [2,] -0.2301775       NA         NA 1.7150650
# [3,]         NA       NA         NA 0.4609162
```

Essentially, you start with creating a `matrix` filled with `NA` values, then you use your "v" (your row indices) to create your column indices as well, subset on that matrix, and replace the values with the values unlisted from "df".

---

`df` in this answer is from useR's answer.